# Entity Framework: Insert a complex model without duplicates but still maintaining relationships

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am trying to insert a complex model into my SQL Server Express database. It posts and saves everything fine, except that I get duplicates of Users that has a many-to-many relationship with multiple Services. Here follows a simplified example of my object structure:

```
public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int ContractNumber { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set;}
}

public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to save a Contract with 3 Services. I also have 3 Users that each belong to all 3 Services, meaning that they exists as duplicates in the 3 Userlists in the Services to get the correct relationships. When I save this object it saves each user 3 times with different Id's with 1 relationship each.

Here's my method for creating and sending the model to my Repository:

```
void Main()
{
    var contract = new Contract
    {
        ContractNumber = 123456,
        Services = new List<Service>()
    };

    var services = new List<Service>
    {
        new Service
        {
            Name = "Service 1",
            Users = new List<User>()
        },
        new Service
        {
            Name = "Service 2",
            Users = new List<User>()
        },
        new Service
        {
            Name = "Service 3",
            Users = new List<User>()
        }
    };

    var users = new List<User>
    {
        new User
        {
            FullName = "User One",
            Email = "user1@mail.com"
        },
        new User
        {
            FullName = "User Two",
            Email = "user2@mail.com"
        },
        new User
        {
            FullName = "User Three",
            Email = "user3@mail.com"
        }
    }

    foreach(var service in services)
    {
        service.Users.AddRange(users);
    }

    contract.Services.AddRange(services);

    var contractRepository = new ContractRepository();

    contractRepository.Add(contract);
    contractRepository.Commit();
}
```

This is a very simplified version. My real data comes from a MVC application but ends up in this format.

My Add method in my Repository looks like this:

```
public void Add(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
    DbSet.Add(entity);         

}
```

and my Commit method:

```
public void Commit()
{
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I make sure that I only save Users once each and make sure that all relationships are maintained? Do I have to save the users first and then add them to the Services or is it possible to save the Contract as one object somehow?

Thanks in advance

Martin Johansson

Comment: Please add the code you are using for adding Users to Services and the other entities to the context.

Comment: Why are you changing entity state to "added" if it is not "detached"?

Comment: The repository part is taken from a pluralsight course and I just haven't looked over it in detail and I'm not up to date with EntryStates. But it will run the else statement if everything is in order.